# How to connect to any specified Wi-Fi network(SSID) using ADB command

Tags: android, adb, amazon-fire-os

Lets assume I have Wi-Fi networks 'A' 'B' & 'C'. I want to connect the connected android device to `SSID`: 'A' which is password protected. Is there a way to perform this using `ADB` command by providing `SSID` and `password` in the same command?

Comment: @Joshua Did you searched the stackoverflow for duplicate question?

Comment: @RickM. can you provide the right ADB command from the link given by you to perform the action I intended, I already searched and I couldn't find it.

Comment: @Manmohan_singh yes I did..

Comment: @SethuramanSrinivasan, I wanted to connect using "ADB" command not using any other code

Comment: is your device rooted?

Comment: Yes @Srini it is rooted

Comment: IMHO, this question was wrongly closed. The first link says nothing about ADB. The second needs root.

Comment: @Joshua Did you get your answer?

Answer (score -2):

```
$ am startservice \
    -n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
    -a WifiSetupService.Connect
```

Go with [android developer console](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/wifi-adb).

Comment: Hi can you explain how to use the argument given in the android developer console to connect to the SSID which is password protected,

Comment: This one is for `Android Things`. Does it work with phones as well?

Comment: Don't think so. Getting this error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad component name: com.google.wifisetup.WifiSetupService`